# How can I omit some fields on swaggo documentation

Tags: json, go, swagger

I'm doing a golang API and need to documentate it. So I'm using swaggo

This a example struct like mine's:

```golang
type calc struct {
   ID int64 `json:"id"`
   Value1 int64 `json:"value1"`
   Value2 int64 `json:"value2"`
   Result int64 `json:"result"`
}
```

Pretend I have two routes:

- Get all calcs (a list)
- Do a calc

Whem doing the docs I specify that the 'Do a calc' route get a json object like calc.

**The problem is**: I'm using this struct to 'read' and 'write', so whem I documentate in the 'Do a calc' route, it means that I need a 'json calc obejct', but **I don't know how to omit the ID and RESULT fields** from the specification (I don't need use this fields on this route, of course).

Comment: I haven't worked with that lib. But my suggestion is using `-` in json tag: ```ID int64 `json:"-"```

Comment: @BogdanDaragan I can't use it because the other route (get all calcs). But if you know some way to change this tag before use the struct it can be helpful I think. Thanks

Comment: Is there any solution for this? Did you find any? @MarceloGonçalves

Comment: @SANDEEPMACHIRAJU I have used two different structs on the routes. But another solution (not so efficient) is use comments: if you comment into the struct, it'll be in model specification on swag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
type calc struct {
   ID int64 `json:"id" swaggerignore:"true"`
   Value1 int64 `json:"value1" `
   Value2 int64 `json:"value2"`
   Result int64 `json:"result" swaggerignore:"true"`
}
```

will omit these fields from your swagger documentation